# Adding a calendar to my website so that users can access their own google calendar

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have imported the google calendar to my website using the api. Have displayed relevant calendar selected from a drop down and deleted calendar events as well. Can someone please tell me how to add a new calendar event from results gathered through the GUI. (It works well from the command line)

ps - I'm writing this in PHP in MVC

Comment: You can embed google calendar to your website by following this link https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en .The collection of calendars in the users calendars list https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList . If user wants to get/create etc in a particular calendar, while sending request to the particular resource, they should give the appropriate calendar ID

Comment: You can get calendar ID from calendar settings->calendars->click on the calendar you want to->check in calendar address

Comment: thank you. thats not what i was looking for. did all of the above except creating and deleting. thanks again